Gobble initial and final vertical spaces in an environment
Is it possible to remove all initial and final vertical spaces from the content of an environment, leaving only the “real” beginning and end of the content?
More specifically, I'd like to manage those vertical spaces myself, so that to always have the same space after the first rule, and before the second one.
In my example code, I would like to eat the space added by the macro \paragraph, and the one due to the use of \bigskip. Is it possible?
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{gobblespaces}{}{
  \rule{.7\textwidth}{0.4pt}% To avoid warning
  \par
}{
  \par
  \rule{.7\textwidth}{0.4pt}% To avoid warning
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gobblespaces}
  \paragraph{Title} Content
  
  Wierd final vertical space
  
  \bigskip
\end{gobblespaces}

\begin{gobblespaces}
  No title: content
  
  No wierd final vertical space
\end{gobblespaces}

\end{document}


you are adding space with your gobblespaces environment not least from the spaces from the ends of lines you have not commented out, but also from parskip glue before the rules.

don't ignore warnings, latex screams at you that you are forcing it to add bad space here. just that small example produces Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 14--15
[][]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 14--15
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 20--21
[][]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 20--21
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 22--24
[][]
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 26--27
[][]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 26--27

@DavidCarlisle How poor my English is... I edited my question to clarify why?

@DavidCarlisle I've been avoiding warnings for a while now, but for the moment I'm faced with another problem. Programming is like dancing: one step at a time... ;-)

I can understand concentrating on one thing at a time, but when latex is warning you that it is adding spurious blank lines, then addressing those warnings or at least mentioning them when asking why you have spurious blank lines would be helpful.

you've again edited your question in a way which partly invalidates @DavidCarlisle's answer. The point about the \textwidth rule now makes no sense as an answer to the new version of the question. please stop making it impossible for later readers to understand the relationship between question and answer.

your edit says "avoid the warning" as if the warning was spurious and you just avoid the message, but you are avoiding the extra space that you were asking about  not all of it: some space still remains but a large part of the space was added by the environment and now the warning goes as you are not adding that space now.

@DavidCarlisle I agree with the spurious spaces. No problem with that.

@cfr I don't agree. I talk about the (user) content of the environment and not the material it adds.

[I see @DavidCarlisle already said this, so I'm not clear what you agree with him but disagree with me about.]

Are you familiar with the \hrule command? If not, give it a try.

@cfr See my comment just after David's answer.

@Mico Yes, but my problem was about the (user) content of the environment. :-)

Yes, so why would one write a multi -step expression if one could write \hrule instead?

Your environment was forcing additional space and warnings as you have a \textwidth wide rule that already does not fit on a line as it is indented, and then has additional white space after words due to missing %.
TeX did warn about the spaces making a blank line  (undefull hbox badness 10000) and the indented rule (ovefull hbox).
\NewDocumentEnvironment{gobblespaces}{}{%%%%%%
  \par
  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%%%%
  \par
}{%%%%%%
  \par
  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%%%%%
  \par
}

would avoid adding space but you can not in general remove space that the content of the enviornment  adds at the start, it depends how it is added.
Similarly you could in some cases detect a skip at the end of the envioenment by consulting \lastskip and adding a negative skip of that amount, but this will only work in some simple cases (eh a color command would add a color restore node and make it impossible to detect that space)

If I understand correctly, it would be possible to eat the spaces created by paragraph and bigskip, but this solution would not work in all situations.

the final bigskip you can spot with \lastskip  you can't spot the space added by \paragraph best you can do is avoid adding it, eg if you used a minipage then latex sets up a fake start of page then heading commands like \paragraph do not add space
